# How to detect whether a sprite wasn´t touched in a certain interval

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I´m sorry that the following question is very specific but I´m looking for more than one hour for a solution of my problem: A sprite changes its color every 3 seconds. I can detect whether the user taps the right color but I cannot detect if the user is just waiting for the next color to score. I tried the following code:

```
private float timeSeconds = 0f;
private float period = 3f;
timeSeconds += Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();    
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                if (executed == true && !(sprite[zahl[i]].getBoundingRectangle().contains(touchPoint.x,
                        touchPoint.y))&& timeSeconds==0 && zahl[4] != zahl[i]) {
                    timeSeconds = 0;
                    this.dispose();
                    game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game, Integer.parseInt(score)));
                    return;
                }
            }
```

This code works partly: If the user doesn´t touch the screen, then the GameOverScreen will be shown. But if the user tapps the right color (=sprite), then the GameOverScreen is also shown. However, I want the game to continue if the user tapps the right sprite, and I want to end the game, which means showing the GameOverScreen, if the user doesn´t tap anything on the screen within three seconds.

Comment: I assume there is a timer of some kind, so you have a boolean you set to true when the right thing is touched. When the timer ends, set it to false if it is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand what you're asking but I think your aim is for the user to touch the screen at least once in 3 seconds. If the user fails to touch in this time then the game over screen is shown. If the user has touched the screen and the right colour sprite was touched add 3 seconds to touch time. Then if user has touched at least 1 right sprite and fails to touch in 3 seconds move to level complete screen.

Let's star with the GameOverScreen. This screen should take your game object, the score and a boolean to say if game ended or completed. Then you can call the game screen with:

```
GameOverScreen(game,score,true); // game completed or
GameOverScreen(game,score,false); // game over
```

Now we have the end screen completed we can add a timer in your game called lastTouched:

```
float lastTouched = 3f; // 3 seconds of touch time
```

Next we add a boolean value so we know if the user touched at least one of the right colour sprites:

```
boolean atLeastOneTouched = false;
```

Now we lower the timer each frame with:

```
lastTouched -= Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
```

We check your sprite touch as usual without the timer stuff:

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            if (executed == true && !(sprite[zahl[i]].getBoundingRectangle().contains(touchPoint.x,
                    touchPoint.y)) && zahl[4] != zahl[i]) {
               // touched right colour
               atLeastOneTouched = true;
               lastTouched = 3f; // reset timer
            }
        }
```

Lastly we check if the timer has run out and then get according screen based on the atLeastOneTouched boolean:

```
if(lastTouched <= 0){
    if(atLeastOneTouched){
        GameOverScreen(game,score,true); // game over complete
    }else{
        GameOverScreen(game,score,false); // game over failed
    }
}
```